# Device portal for Win 10 mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-10-iot-core

Is there a way to install the Device portal from Windows 10 IoT Core to Windows 10 Mobile and desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about desktop, but it is actually present on mobile version. Just go to **Settings**, select **Update & security**, then **For developers**. Activate **Device discovery** and **Device portal**. You will see a URL address to which you can connect. After entering the page with a browser from PC, you need to enter PIN - it will be generated by your phone (tap **Pair** in Device discovery).

Answer (score 0):

To build on Ondrej's answer - Device Portal will ship on desktop and Xbox dev kits as well with the Anniversary Update of Windows 10. It's currently in the Windows Insider flights.